# How to Use Pandas with Multiple Column NumPy Array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Okay, I'm stumped on this. I've looked at the `Pandas` documentation but I can't figure out the right way to do it and I think I'm just making a mess. Basically, I have data which are `NumPy` arrays.

For example:

```
data = numpy.loadtxt('foo.txt', dtype=str,delimiter=',') 
gps_data = numpy.concatenate((data[0:len(data),0:2],data[0:len(data),3:5]),axis=1)
gps_time = data[0:len(data),2:3].astype(numpy.float)/1000
```

The `gps_data` basically looks like this:

```
array([['50.3482627', '-71.662499', '30', 'network'],
       ['50.3482588', '-71.6624934', '30', 'network'],
       ['50.34829', '-71.6625077', '30', 'network'],
       ...,
       ['20.3482488', '-78.66245463999999', '9', 'gps'],
       ['20.3482598', '-78.6625174', '30', 'network'],
       ['20.34824943', '-78.6624565', '10', 'gps']],
      dtype='|S18')
```

and the `gps_time`:

```
array([[  1.16242035e+09],
       [  1.26242036e+09],
       [  1.36242038e+09],
       ...,
       [  1.32330411e+09],
       [  1.16330413e+09],
       [  1.26330413e+09]])
```

What I'm trying to do is use `DataFrame` to bring another similar looking array called `acc_data`, combine it with `gps_data` and then go back through and fill in the different missing data times.

This is what I've been trying:

```
df1 = DataFrame(gps_data,index=gps_time,columns=['GPS'])
```

But it gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 35047), indices imply (1, 35047)
```

Which I don't know how to handle. If I can find a way around that, then I assume the next step `df2` but for `acc_data` will work fine and then I can do:

```
p = Panel({'ACC': df1, 'GPS': df2})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i have been stumped on this for last few hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you pass in as many column names (using the `columns` keyword) as there are columns in your NumPy array:

```
df1 = DataFrame(gps_data, index=gps_time, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
```

Pandas raises the error because you've given it an array with four columns and it only has one column name, `'GPS'`, which you've specified.

Comment: Sweet thanks, although now when I do p = Panel({'GPS':df1,'ACC':df2}) it complains buffer has wrong number of dimensions expected 1 found 2. ?

Comment: No problem. What is your `df2`? What shape is it?

Comment: df2 is [7111 rows x 3 columns] (sorry I don't know how to do formatting properly in comments) But basically df2 looks like:

                      x          y          z
1.362420e+09  -0.249893   4.125504   9.105667
1.362420e+09  -2.738571   5.260941   8.285629

Comment: @eWizardII Hmmm... I can't seem to replicate the error and I'm afraid I haven't played around with Panel a great deal. [It might be a bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4937) if you're using an older version of Pandas. If not, perhaps asking a new question is the way to go...

Comment: Alright will do thanks! I have version 0.14.1 on Windows which should be the latest version or close to it I believe.

Answer (score 2):

[ajcr is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26222232/190597); the error can be avoided by specifying the right number of columns. Since `gps_data` has shape (35047, 4), the DataFrame has four columns. So you need `columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']` if you are going to specify column names.

To get `gps_data` in the right shape, it would also be easier to use

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.genfromtxt('foo.txt', dtype=None, delimiter=',',
                     usecols=[0,1,2,3,4])
gps_data = data[:, [0,1,3,4]]
gps_time = data[:, 2]/1000.0
```

and then you can build the DataFrame with

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(gps_data, index=gps_time)
```

---

**Caveats**:

```
gps_time = data[0:len(data),2:3]
```

makes gps_time 2-dimensional with shape (35047, 1). If you use

```
gps_time = data[0:len(data),2]
```

then `gps_time` will be 1-dimensional, with shape (35047,).  This is more likely what you want, since the index (time) appears to be 1-dimensional.

---

```
data = numpy.loadtxt('foo.txt', dtype=str,delimiter=',')
```

makes all your numbers strings. If you use

```
np.genfromtxt('foo.txt', dtype=None, )
```

the `dtype=None` tells `genfromtxt` to make an intelligent guess about the type of each column -- so your float-like numbers will automatically have dtype float.

Comment: Alright I'll try this also - it might be the cause of the problem I just followed up too the other answer below that I get an error when using Panel.