# Pandas Creating Panel from Multiple DataFrames Buffer Has Wrong Dimesnions

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, panel, dataframe

This is a continuation of an early [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222192/how-to-use-pandas-with-multiple-column-numpy-array) for which a solution was found to create DataFrames, my issue now is making the Panel. I'm doing the following:

```
df1 = DataFrame(gps_data, index=gps_time, columns=['lat', 'lon', 'error', 'service'])
df2 = DataFrame(acc_data, index=acc_time, columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
df3 = DataFrame(batt_data, index=batt_time, columns=['pct'])

p = Panel({'GPS':df1,'ACC':df2,'BATT':df3})
```

Which returns the following error

> ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)

I'm unsure of why this is. `df1` is `[35047 rows x 4 columns]`, `df2` is `[7111 rows x 3 columns]`, and `df3` is `[512 rows x 1 columns]`. Any help would be appreciated greatly! So close.